# How to reference a specific Group Total of one dataset in the expression in different dataset

Tags: matrix, grouping, ssrs-2008

I have a report with multiple datasets. In one of them I need to reference the group total from another dataset. It looks like this:

Tablix1:

```
Region1   Total    Age1    Age2
   a       7        5      2
   b       12       6      6
   c       20       12     8
Total      39       23     16
```

Tablix2:

```
Region2   Value      %
   a       4      57.14%
   b       6      50.00%
   c       5      25.00%
```

The values in the "%" column of Tablix2 come from formula: %a = Tablix2 Value a / Tablix1 Total a.

My current expression in % column of Tablix2 looks like:

```
=CountDistinct(Fields!ID.Value, "Region2")/CountDistinct(Fields!CONSTITUENT_ID.Value, "Tablix1")
```

but what I get is the percentage calculated of the Total row of Tablix1 and not each Region of Tablix1.

Answer (score 1):

The Lookup function would work for this. It's similar to a vlookup in Excel. It would look something like this:

```
=Lookup(Fields!Region1.Value, Fields!Region2.Value, Fields!ID.Value, "Region2")
```

This would pull the corresponding value from Region 2 into Tablix 1. You can just switch it around if you want it in the other table.